# Asking about if conditional in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array structure like this:

```
array[1].name = "parameter-name";
array[1].value = null;
array[2].name = null;
array[2].value = "parameter-value2";
```

i want to change `null` to `""`.

This is how I display in ajax:

```
for (var i in array) {

    if(array[i].name == null) {
            array[i].name = "";
    } 
    if(array[i].value == null) {
            array[i].value = ""; 
    }
}
```

How to make if condition all item of the array?

```
for (var i in array) {

    if(array[i] == null) {
        array[i] = "";
    } 

}
```

I tried this but the result is error on JavaScript.

Comment: `array[i]name` is not going to work. Why don't you fix that first. Just out of curiosity, why do want to replace `null` with an empty string?

Comment: @torazaburo on my ajax result thats works for me, but i have randomly null value from database, i want to convert it to empty string for my web view

Answer (score 2):

```
array.map(({name, value}) => ({
   name : (name === null) ? "" : name,
   value : (value === null) ? "" : value    
}))
```

Assuming you are checking equality EXACTLY  with `null` (not `undefined` or `false` or something else),That's why we are using `x === null` instead of `!x`.

```js
const array = [
  {name: "Something", value: null},
  {name: "SomethingB", value: "ValB"},
  {name: null, value: "ValC"},
]
   
 console.log(  
    array.map(({name, value}) => ({
       name : (name === null) ? "" : name,
       value : (value === null) ? "" : value    
    }))
    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One another implementation using the `||` operator, which can be used to set the **default** values.

To set default values using the `||`, you can use code like

```
var value = expressionToEvaluate || defaultValue;
```

If expressionToEvaluate is *falsey*, then the `value` would be assigned the `defaultValue`. It would be useful to know about the *falsey* value in Javascript.

**Complete working code:**

```js
var array = [{name: "parameter-name1", value: null},
  {name: null, value: "parameter-value2"},
  {name: null, value: null }
];


array.forEach(x => { x.name = x.name || "";
                     x.value = x.value || ""});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: NOPE.. `(a || b)` works with 6 cases  `null` , `undefined`, `false`, `0` , empty string OR not owned property.. However the question is exactly about `null`.

Comment: I agree that's the reason in the answer, i have also written about the falsey values.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the transformation from null to empty string on **all** properties, in place (mutating the original array):

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const elt = array[i];

  for (let prop in elt) {
    if (elt[prop] === null) elt[prop] = '';
  }

}
```

Note that we are not using `in` to loop over elements in the array, as that is generally considered bad practice.